# How do I attach an unnamed tmux session?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

`tmux ls` gives me the following result:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-x-y-z:~$ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 23 08:35:32 2017) [112x51]
1: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 23 09:06:27 2017) [112x51]
```

**How do I attach the the first one in the list?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your own answer is one way, with `-t`.

If you are already in one tmux session, you can `PREFIX+s` to let tmux show you a session list, thus, you can select the session you want to attach.

Or just `tmux attach` to attach the first session, then do the above step.

Answer (score 6):

I have figured out the answer:

`tmux attach -t 0`

`0` and `1` are the pid's of the sessions and they can be attached using those pid's after the `attach` command.